# Getting the standard deviation of a Eigen::vector

Tags: c++, eigenvector

I  need to have standard deviation of a vector in [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixArithmetic.html) library. I have not found it. So i tried it:

```
Eigen::VectorXd ys(5);
 ys << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5;            

double std_dev = sqrt((ys - ys.mean()).square().sum() / (ys.size() - 1)); // Error with minus sign (ys-ys.mean())
```

But getting error.

error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0349   no operator "-" matches these operands
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [`Eigen::VectorXd` is defined as `typedef Matrix<double, Dynamic, 1> VectorXd;`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-3.2/group__matrixtypedefs.html) so it is a special form of an `Eigen::Matrix`. You are trying to subtract a scalar `ys.mean()` from a vector `ys` which is an coefficient-wise operation. **The `Eigen::Matrix` class is not intended to be used with coefficient-wise operations but for linear algebra.**  For performing coefficient-wise operations Eigen has the [**`Eigen::Array` class**](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html).

Therefore it is sufficient to **convert your `Eigen::Matrix` `ys` to an `Eigen::Array`** for your formula to work:

```
double const std_dev = sqrt((ys.array() - ys.mean()).square().sum() / (ys.size() - 1));
```

Comment: I think you're missing a set of parentheses...
```double const std_dev = sqrt(((ys.array() - ys.mean()).square().sum() / (ys.size() - 1)));
```

Comment: @random_dsp_guy The additional parenthesis you added should not be necessary.